# how to develop asp.net in a team using TFS when adding a referance breaks others builds when they get latest version?

Tags: asp.net

What is the best practice for not breaking builds for team members working on asp.net website code base using TFS?

I keep seeing a single developer adding a reference to get their code to work and checking it in, then when everyone else gets latest version they lack the reference on their dev machines and get broken builds and have to waste time hunting for resolutions.

Aside from emailing the team when someone adds a new reference is there something inherent to VS that can be used?

Can we pull a separate project and refer to that as a redundancy and keep all resource dlls and references there?

Comment: stop the single developer from checking in without a code review? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) describes many working scenarios. It's long but worth reading.

[Guidance for Structuring Team Projects](http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidance%20for%20Structuring%20Team%20Projects)

I've always kept third party DLLs in a project folder under source control, so that a get-latest pulls them down.

Of interest?: [Visual Studio 2010 Quick Reference Guidance](http://vs2010quickref.codeplex.com/)